# Compare non-Copy enum inside reference of Cell

Tags: rust

I got a reproduction project here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08e0f111394174b76ab788f784918dca and below is the code also.

I am having trouble matching an `Enum` inside a `Cell`, whereas the enum is not `Copy`, because one of its fields is a `String`. The input is a reference to a `Cell` (in my 'real' code, so to demonstrate my problem, I made it a reference in the example code also).

I do not want to use a `RefCell`, because that can crash and I don't want to do error handling each time when trying to match the `Enum` across the project.

I tried a `match` expression, trying to search for a `get` method, but that's only available on `Copy` types inside a `Cell`. I don't care if a `clone` method is invoked somewhere.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(PartialEq, Clone)]
enum SoftDrink {
    Cola,
    Unknown(String)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(true, is_cola(&Cell::new(SoftDrink::Cola)));
    assert_eq!(false, is_cola(&Cell::new(SoftDrink::Unknown("Fanta".to_owned()))));
}

fn is_cola(drink: &Cell<SoftDrink>) -> bool {
    // ??
}
```

Comment: "not `RefCell`, because that can crash" – if you actually have concurrent mutable access to the same memory location in your codebase, you can't make that problem go away by using `Cell` instead; you will need proper locking. If you don't have concurrent mutable access, `RefCell` will never panic.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's a good point, maybe I should combine it with a Mutex?

Comment: We don't really have enough information about your use case. In the code you shared, the easiest solution would be not to use `Cell` at all, and instead use a simple reference. A `Mutex` is only needed when you have multiple threads. In single-threaded context, `RefCell` will be enough.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ok, I provided not enough information. My use-case is a `struct` which holds a property which I need to modify across threads, while that `struct` is passed as immutable to functions.

Comment: Then you will need some kind of locking. You can't get a reference to a value that someone else might change at any time, since this would break one of Rust's fundamental guarantees about references. One common approach is using `Arc<RwLock<SoftDrink>>`. This can be shared across threads and borrowed immutably as long as no thread currently holds a mutable borrow. `RwLock::read()` will block the current thread until the read lock can be acquired.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks, I ended up doing that and now it's working. I didn't see the main problem at first (concurrency) :)